# Overall Probability

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Using 2 sports teams, team A and B:

Team A's win probability based on historical data:

On Mondays is 80%;
Against team B is 40%;
Recent form is 70%;
At home is 60%

How do you find 1 overall probability based on those numbers?

Comment: This isn't a math problem, not really.  Sports tends to have a huge number of external factors involved.  Is a key player out?  Is one team or the other coming off a string of exhausting back to back games? And so on.  There's a reason that professional handicappers are very well paid.

Comment: Agree with the above comment -- any solution requires simplifying assumptions that are almost always unrealistic in practice, usually unrealistic enough so as to make the proposed answer irrelevant.

Comment: I'm only asking for an equation to that figures out overall probability.  I fully understand there is.more to it.  This was just a small example

Comment: As the comments suggest, there is no such formula.

Answer (score 1):

Probability requires assumptions in order to make calculations. Determining what those assumptions should be is more art than science, and in this case, it's sports not maths.

If you assumed that those factors were independent, all equally important, and you had no more relevant information that you could include, then you can just multiply them all together: $0.8\times 0.4\times 0.7\times 0.6 = 0.1344$.

**However**, I want to emphasise that this is not "an equation [that] figures out [the] overall probability". They are probabilities in a *model* that has a number of (very flawed) *modelling assumptions*. Working out how to refine the modelling assumptions to get slightly less bad estimates is a career, not a StackExchange question.

Comment: Thanks, that is where my model is at now...I just didn't know if there was another equation I was missing because whenever I multiply those together the sets never =1

Comment: Well said - equations come from models, models come from making assumptions about how different factors fit together. Because there is no "correct" way to make such assumptions, there is no "correct" equation for the overall probability. Admittedly most textbooks on probability do the reader a disservice but deliberately avoiding addressing/discussing this reality, and in fact most solutions to textbook probability problems require implicitly familiarizing oneself with implicit "usual simplifying assumptions". (Admittedly this is also what I dislike about physics textbook problems too.)